# What genre is Magicka: Wizard Wars' (Competitive Arena Fighting Game) "Main Menu Theme”?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

I am looking for music similar to *Magicka: Wizard Wars*' (Competitive Arena Fighting Game) soundtrack, "Main Menu Theme."

The music was composed by [Johan Lindgren](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm7651914/).

---

This is one version of this song:--

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ez2YwfEayyg)

---

**Questions**:--

1. What genre(s) of music does this song belong to?
2. What modern or old composers is this song inspired by?

---

**Prior Research**:--

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magicka)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_game)
- (https://www.gamesradar.com/au/magicka-wizard-wars/)
- (https://magicka.gamepedia.com/Magicka:_Wizard_Wars)
- (https://www.imdb.com/name/nm7651914/)

I've gone through all these above sources and they contain little-to-no information regarding the soundtrack and/or the composer(s) of the game. Thus, I've decided to ask the question here.

I could not find a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=magicka%20wizard%20wars&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1) specifically for *Wizard Wars*.

Some of Paradox titles may have [educational value](https://web.a.ebscohost.com/abstract?direct=true&profile=ehost&scope=site&authtype=crawler&jrnl=10257861&asa=Y&AN=122780260&h=hAbglEDNsvLNFXucvBkMP4%2FD4QIh%2B8bbT%2Baq%2F2zbFI%2FNZSERoa1eGJJZ7ziRujV6GjqZL1LssMVJo2xLhJRRzg%3D%3D&crl=c&resultNs=AdminWebAuth&resultLocal=ErrCrlNotAuth&crlhashurl=login.aspx%3Fdirect%3Dtrue%26profile%3Dehost%26scope%3Dsite%26authtype%3Dcrawler%26jrnl%3D10257861%26asa%3DY%26AN%3D122780260). That is my partial motivation for studying these games. I am serious about this interest.

Comment: Sorry, do not know the genre or similar composers. But when I want similar music I get a lot of results in youtube by simply searching for "Fairytale music" or "Dark fairytale music". There is one channel that constantly puts out things that sound almost identical to the one you posted: "Fantasy & World Music by the Fiechters"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can't respond right now because one of my relatives is not well. Good thoughts, good words, and good deeds.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius NP. Thank you for your comment. I understand and I will consider your suggestion of search terms. :) ^^ :D 